# Cartesian and Polar Coordinates, proving the same number-pair

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

The question states:

Prove that a necessary and sufficient condition for a point to be represented by the same number-pair (a,b) both cartesian and polar coordinates is that it lies on the initial line.

I do not want answers to the question, I just want some guidance towards the question, since I'm confused with what it is asking.

- By same number-pair, does it mean a=b?
- Lies on the initial line?

I'm confused by both of these statements, can somebody provide some hints or help to this question?

Comment: Not sure, but I'd think same pair means $x = r$, $y = \phi$. Have no idea what initial line means.